# Python - Recursive Formula

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

In a tutorial that I am working through, there's sample code of a tree being drawn with different levels of branches. I am trying to write a function that displays the number of branches when the "level" of the tree changes "denoted by N".

In the code below, the two commented # lines below show what I am trying to accomplish. I completely understand that when N is incremented by 1, the number of branches added to the tree is a multiple of 3, but I do not understand how to utilize a function `count_num_branches()` to display the number of branches on the tree at each recursive call.

```
__author__ = 'Python Tutotial'
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi
import turtle

""" Run with br = 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 and put together a recursive formula
that can be used to determine the count)num_branches.
"""

def tree(t, n, x, y, a, branchRadius):
    global count
    count += 1
    bendAngle   = radians(15)
    branchAngle = radians(37)
    branchRatio = .65

    cx = x + cos(a) * branchRadius
    cy = y + sin(a) * branchRadius

    t.width(1 * n ** 1.2)
    if t.pensize() < .3:
        t.color('pink')
    else:
        t.color('black')

    t.goto(x, y)
    t.down()
    t.goto(cx, cy)
    t.up()
    if not n:
        return None

    tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle - branchAngle, branchRadius * branchRatio)
    tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle + branchAngle, branchRadius * branchRatio)
    tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle,               branchRadius * (1 - branchRatio))

# def count_num_branches(br):

def main():
    global count
    count = 0
    N = 1  #Run with N = 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 1, 1)
    wn.bgcolor('cyan')
    wn.title("My Tree  N = "+str(N))
    #t.speed(0)
    turtle.tracer(15)
    t.ht()
    t.up()
    tree(t, N, .5, 0, pi/2, .3)
    # wn.title("My Tree  N = {0}, Recursive calls: {1:,} count_num_branches = {2:,}".format(N, count, count_num_branches(br)))
    wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The number of lines drawn is the same as the recursive call count.  For N = 1, you get a recursive call count of 4 and there are 4 lines on the screen, a trunk and three branches.  So branch count can be computed -- what is it you want to display (e.g. the "leaves" at the outer edge of the tree, etc.)

Comment: This line Here: wn.title("My Tree  N = {0}, Recursive calls: {1:,} count_num_branches = {2:,}".format(N, count, count_num_branches(br))) should use a function count_num_branches to display the current value of N, the count of the recursive call and the total number of branches including the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you describe -- but I'm still not sure it does what you want.  It basically calculates recursions/branches two different ways: once by counting; once by recursive formula:

```
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

branchRatio = .65
bendAngle = radians(15)
branchAngle = radians(37)

def tree(t, n, x, y, a, branchRadius):
    global count
    count += 1

    cx = x + cos(a) * branchRadius
    cy = y + sin(a) * branchRadius

    t.width(1 * n ** 1.2)
    t.color('pink' if t.width() < 0.3 else 'black')

    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.goto(cx, cy)
    t.penup()

    if n > 0:
        tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle - branchAngle, branchRadius * branchRatio)
        tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle + branchAngle, branchRadius * branchRatio)
        tree(t, n-1, cx, cy, a + bendAngle, branchRadius * (1 - branchRatio))

def count_num_branches(n):
    branches = 1

    if n > 0:
        branches += 3 * count_num_branches(n - 1)

    return branches

N = 3  # Run with N = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 1, 1)
screen.bgcolor('cyan')
screen.title("My Tree:  N = {0}".format(N))
screen.tracer(15)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
#turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

count = 0
tree(turtle, N, .5, 0, pi/2, .3)

screen.title("My Tree:  N = {0}, Recursive calls = {1:,}, # Branches = {2:,}".format(N, count, count_num_branches(N)))
screen.exitonclick()
```